# How can I refine PHP sub-string and chop functions

Tags: php, string, substr, chop

I have the PHP code below, so my question is how can I refine it?

```
$slug                   = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$myslug                 = substr($slug, 4);
$new_slug               = chop($myslug,"?lang=fr");
```

Comment: What do you mean by refine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eliminate all those variables.

```
$slug = chop(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 4),"?lang=fr");
```